# Flutter prevent TextField nestedscrollview

Tags: flutter

How to prevent **Textfield** scrolling when text is longer then screen height the problem is that I have **CustomScrollView** inside of it horizontal **ListView** and **textfield** and I want that when you scroll text inside textfield it would scroll with ListView now it scrolls just text and leaves ListView pinned to the place, but if you scroll while tapping outside textfield it works as expected.

Seems that nested scrollview would solve such problem but no idea how to implement it with two child widgets

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NestedScrollView and a controller and then ListView will work.